# Update millions of records

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update

I'm using MS SQL and have a table with millions of activities from hundreds of cost centers for workorders. We would like to analyse the data according to our different management levels and our reporting structure. Therefore I'm trying to update the data with the records from the master data table.

So far everything works fine but it's way too slow. This is how I do it at the moment:

```
UPDATE [Activity - E].dbo.td_Import
SET [Sender.Type]               = tmp_CC.[Type],
    [Sender.Person Responsible] = tmp_CC.[Person Responsible],
    [Sender.Level1]             = tmp_CC.[Level 1],
    [Sender.Level2]             = tmp_CC.[Level 2],
    [Sender.Level3]             = tmp_CC.[Level 3],
    [Sender.Level4]             = tmp_CC.[Level 4],
    [Sender.Active]             = tmp_CC.[Active]

FROM (  SELECT [Cost Center], [Type], [Person Responsible], [Level 1], [Level 2], [Level 3], [Level 4], [Active]
        FROM [Master Data - E].dbo.md_CostCenter md_CC
        WHERE (md_CC.[Record Invalid] LIKE '') OR (md_CC.[Record invalid] IS NULL)) tmp_CC  
WHERE ([Sender.CC] LIKE tmp_CC.[Cost Center]) AND ([Sender.Type] IS }NULL)
```

I have to run similar code five times and it take about 90 minutes to update all records. Since the data should be provided to the management around the clock I have only a short window of about two hours to get the data, update all information and create individual reports for the managers (excel report, every report take about 10 minutes by macro).

I was thinking about joining the data with the master data table but I got totally lost in all the tutorials. All I got was some temporary table but nothing was stored in my activity table (td_Import).

Any advice for a beginner? Thanks a lot in advance.

Chris

Comment: This sounds like a job for analysis services, perhaps look at building one or more cubes.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but I don't see the relationship between the table you are updating and the subquery in the same update statement.

Comment: Actually some of your SQL can be refactored but I'm on my phone right now. If no-one has responded I'll help you out later.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's in the where clause. Very old school way of writing SQL

Comment: I'm trying to create the basic table for an analysis cube. There are about 100+ columns, some coming from SAP others from excel and they should all be combined in one big table. The table will be droped and recreated at least every 24 hours with the latest data.

Comment: Your statement (however written unconventionally) should get descend execution plan. You might want to add a index on [Sender.CC] if you haven't already. Updating this much data will cause loads of page splits and will take a while depending on drive performance and clustered index configuration. Inserting the result of the join in an other table would probably improve performance drastically.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally got the concept of Join.

The following code improved the run time from over 30 to 3 minutes on 1.1 million records.
Also, I included a view to reduce the selection of the valid cost centers (View [Active Cost Centers]).

```
UPDATE [Activity - E].dbo.td_Import 
    SET [Sender.Type]               = md_CC.[Type],
        [Sender.Person Responsible] = md_CC.[Person Responsible],
        [Sender.Level1]             = md_CC.[Level 1],
        [Sender.Level2]             = md_CC.[Level 2],
        [Sender.Level3]             = md_CC.[Level 3],
        [Sender.Level4]             = md_CC.[Level 4],
        [Sender.Active]             = md_CC.[Active]
    FROM [Activity - E].dbo.td_Import td_Imp 
        LEFT JOIN [Master Data - E].dbo.[Active Cost Centers] md_CC
        ON td_Imp.[Sender.CC] LIKE md_CC.[Cost Center]
```

I hope this will be helpful to others.

Chris